# Is there "video evidence that [Palestinians] deliberately avoided targeting women and children" during the Oct 7 attacks on Israel?

Tags: israel, palestine, israel-hamas-war

*Forward*, an American Jewish newspaper, [reports](https://forward.com/fast-forward/568890/queens-college-cuny-frank-wu-denounce-hamas-denial/) that Queens College, City of New York University had a Muslim student group posting Instagram stories defending Palestinian/Hamas attacks on Israel on October 7, 2023.

> ZERO evidence that Palestinians deliberately killed women and children. **There is a great deal of video evidence that they deliberately *avoided* targeting women and children.** There is nothing wrong with Palestinians taking prisoners of war in their struggle against the Zionist terror occupation. We cannot allow the Zionist false narrative (to) become the accepted history of what happened.”

[A putative screenshot of the message is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGiW0.jpg)

The first claim is trivially disprovable. I am curious about the second claim:  there is video evidence that Palestinians did not target civilians.

Is it true?

Comment: [Sorry, but we don't care about your political opinions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/sorry-but-we-dont-care-about-your-political-opinions) in chat.

Comment: Is the claim in question that some *individual* Palestinians participating in the attack avoided targeting women and children, or that the Palestinian forces *as a group* avoided it?  The latter seems more consistent with the narrative that I imagine the protesters trying to convey, and more relevant, but much harder to reconcile with the available evidence.

Comment: To me the article reads as "Hamas wasn't overall targeting civilians to kill, only to kidnap". That ... seems like an interesting Q. But the one answer so far is answering the different Q "did Hamas kidnap civilians?" Wonder if what the article claims could be clarified?

Comment: @OwenReynolds: no, clarifications are not allowed (by the mods of this site). Your comment will soon be deleted, probably. Like some similar ones that already were.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the latter. Otherwise even one Palestinian who didn't kill a civilian would be enough. The "they" is a collective they - there was a main group behind the attack that did not intend to (even if some did).

Comment: @Fizz Gah! I just noticed that this Q is junk, and there won't be any details. It's some Jewish newspaper accusing some Muslim group of posting something on Instagram. So, not noteworthy and barely even a claim.

Comment: @OwenReynolds: I suspect the original claim was trying to point to some specific Hamas propaganda videos that (interestingly) have been discussed in Western MSM sources, but that comment was deleted, so I won't repost that very specifically. It's also not the case that there was a "great deal" of them, although that term is also a bit interpretable. To someone (with enough bias) a single video may be a "great deal of evidence".

Comment: Reminder: we don't accept pseudo-answers in comments. If you want to answer the question, use an answer box where it can be edited and voted upon.

Comment: Please change the word "Palestinians" in the title to "Hamas" or "terrorists" or even "Palestinian terrorists". The behavior of some shouldn't be used to refer to the whole group. Just like we refer to attacks by "extremist settlers" and not "Israelis" in the West Bank...

Comment: @hb20007: I understand your point, but this is the text of the claim. Such clarification belongs in an answer.

Comment: @TheAsh : can you edit the question to include the precision from your last comment ?

Comment: I would suggest the question title be edited to replace "Palestinians" with "Hamas terrorist", the rest looks fine to me.

Comment: @Fizz: That is not a fair characterisation. Answers in comments aren't permitted. When it comes to defining the claim, we should use the definitions the *claimant* intended (and steel-man when we aren't sure) so asking the OP what the Instagram meant isn't very helpful. On the other hand, if the OP explains what they understand it may lead to frame challenge answers where the intended definitions are explained.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan: That seems like it is  is changing the claim though. Consider whether this caused controversy precisely because the claim is worded in a way to misrepresent the situation.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Using the term "Hamas" is also contentious, because other groups, such as Lion's Den or Islamic Jihad, were involved as well. Someone might claim that some of those groups committed atrocities, but the others didn't. I think it's fair write "Palestinians", just like it's fair to write that "Israel" is bombing Gaza without specifying it's the IDF doing so.

Comment: This question has an implicit underlying assumptions that the attackers had one coordinated policy regarding this matter. Please remember that the attack involved multiple armed wings (of Hamas, Islamic Jihad, PFLP, DFLP, a bit of Fatah, popular resistance committes and maybe others) + unaffiliated people just spilling out of the hole in the fence. It is obvious (well, if you followed a lot of media) that different people in different, or the same, factions behaved completely differently towards civilians. Some avoided attacking civilians, some attacked ruthlessly, some in between.

Comment: @gerrit I would still be hesitant tbh. One may, perhaps, simply specify the groups and put an "etc.". For example, "Hamas, Lion's Den, Hezbollah, Islamic Jihad, etc.". And the comparison with IDF and Israel is not the same as IDF is an official government organization of Israel. So Israel is, effectively, bombing Gaza, and IDF, as a govenrment organization is a face of it. On the other hand, one cannot say that Hamas, or any of those group are an official face of Palestine as a state because they aren't official government organizations, simply militant groups who tend to takeover stuff.

Comment: Do note that I am not stating this to state my political opinion in any manner, simply suggesting a correction towards the terminology used. However, I do find the other reasoning strong that the reason it is there is to quote the American Jewish newspaper properly.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Arguably, Hamas is as much officially representing Gaza as the Taliban is officially representing Afghanistan. One can debate their legitimacy, but whether we like it or not, they are in charge (for IDF/Israel this is contested only by Iran & allies who don't recognise Israel's right to exist). So I think one could argue for the claim that Hamas are in an official position (and one could argue against it).

Comment: @gerrit That is debatable, but even then, it wouldn't apply to the entirety of Palestine (Palestinians), because well... Palestine consists of more than Gaza :) but at this point, I don't think the title should be changed due to the reason provided by the other user, so we are on the same page.

Comment: @einpoklum "Some avoided attacking civilians, some attacked ruthlessly, some in between" Source for that? Such a claim is worthy of a question of its own.

Comment: @C.F.G the original claim was regarding the Oct 7th attacks.

Comment: Is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGiW0.jpg) the entire message? If not, where is the rest of it?

Answer (score 71):

There is clear evidence that the terrorists attacking Israel on Oct 7th were deliberately targeting civilians and civilian population centers.

There are plenty of video evidence of them targeting, shooting at and killing civilians. Just looking at the huge list of victims we see the tens of murdered children and hundreds of murdered women, youngest of them (of all those whose identity was released by now) is [10 month old Mila Cohen](https://www.jns.org/three-generations-wiped-out-by-hamas-in-kibbutz-beeri/).

We also have the identity of the kidnapped confirmed by Hamas and PIJ. [Hamas released two elderly women](https://www.timesofisrael.com/two-israeli-hostages-nurit-cooper-79-and-yocheved-lifshitz-85-released-from-gaza/), Yocheved Lifshitz, 85 years old and Nurit Cooper, 79 years old. There is no way that a reasonable person will think that two elderly women are IDF soldiers or part of the Israeli military forces. Earlier they released mother and daughter [Judith and Natalie Raanan](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-67276547), 59 and 18 years old. And released a video showing three women they hold captive [Rimon Buchshtav Kirsht, Danielle Aloni and Lena Trupanov](https://people.com/family-kidnapped-woman-rimon-kirsht-cruel-hostage-video-exclusive-8386040), aged 36, 44 and 50. [PIJ released a video](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/islamic-jihad-airs-propaganda-clip-with-signs-of-life-from-2-hostages/) confirming that they hold Hannah Katzir, 77 years old, and Yagil Yaakov, 13 years old. We have terrorist confirmation that they took captive and hold elderly women and children. None of them are military members and can't be confused as military members. All taken from their civilian homes in civilian clothes.

We have the story of the [Elyakim-Arava family](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dyVUwDu52k&ab_channel=%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9F%7C%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%92%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99) (video from the news, shows blood). The father Noam Elyakim and his two daughters Ella and Dafna aged 8 and 15 and his girlfriend Dikla Arava and her son Tomer, 17 years old. They were filmed in Hamas captivity in their home alive and well except for a minor wound in Noam's leg. Later on Oct 7<sup>th</sup> there are pictures of Ella and Dafna in Hamas captivity. In the following days and weeks the bodies of Noam, Dikla and Tomer were found. They were killed by Hamas while they were kidnapped from their home and were in their custody.

There is plenty more evidence from the day of the attack made and published by Hamas themselves where we can clearly see women and children kidnapped. [This news video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuZ-WfOxPXo&ab_channel=%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%9A%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99) contains some of the published clips, but not all of them (clip is SFW), in the following time stamps:

- 0:46 - Women and children from Nir Oz
- 1:30 - Elyakim-Arava family
- 5:00 - Yafa Hadar, 85 years old woman.
- 7:15 - Noa Argamani, a young woman who was kidnapped from the Nova music festival.

The video contains also footage of kidnaped civilian men, but for some reason QCMSA don't concern themselves about them. And these are not the only videos in existence, there are other, more gruesome.

Dead civilians: many women and children were killed, just one example from Kibbutz Be'eri shows four hostages led by Hamas terrorists handcuffed, and in a later video they are shown dead next to the gate of the Kibbutz. From a [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/investigations/2023/10/09/israel-hamas-hostage-death/)

> At least four Israelis taken hostage by Hamas during their unprecedented incursion into Israel on Saturday were killed soon after being taken captive, according to videos reviewed by The Washington Post. Graphic video shared on Telegram on Oct. 8, and verified by The Post, shows multiple bodies in the street in Be’eri, a kibbutz in southern Israel, just yards from where Hamas militants were filmed walking with several civilians who appear to be those same hostages.
>
> Initial video of the hostages, which was filmed roughly an hour and a half after the attack began, was among the first pieces of visual evidence showing Hamas militants taking Israeli civilians captive.
>
> In the video, the civilians appear to have their hands tied behind their backs and are being led by men in military clothing carrying AR-style weapons down a residential street. Some walk barefoot. Black smoke billows in the distance. The person filming shouts toward the group as they approach an intersection that is guarded by a gate, leading out of Be’eri toward Gaza.
>
> At least four bodies are visible near that gate, in a second graphic video shared on Telegram on Oct. 8, which was independently verified by The Post and first geolocated by Rollo Collins and Benjamin den Braber of the Center for Information Resilience. The Post was not able to immediately verify exactly when this video was filmed, though burned cars and smoke are visible in both videos.

There is the video of the death of Osama Abu Essa an Israeli Arab Bedouin who was held by Hamas, interrogated, abused and then murdered, captured by a dash cam. I'm not linking to the video, because gore and snuff, you can look at [the question on this site about him](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56283/did-the-family-of-osama-abu-essa-a-bedouin-man-killed-by-hamas-offer-a-1m-rew)

And the story of 22 years old East Jerusalem Palestinian driver [Suhaib Razeem](https://www.timesofisrael.com/newly-released-footage-shows-palestinian-driver-in-hamas-hands-before-oct-7-slaying/):

> Footage emerged on Tuesday showing the moment Razeem was captured by Hamas terrorists, some of whom apparently intended to let him go at first, upon finding out he was an Arab.
>
> In the video clip, published by the South First Responders group on Telegram, one terrorist asks him “Are you an Arab?” to which Razeem replies “Jerusalemite.” Another one asked to see his ID.
>
> A third terrorist asks “What are you doing here?” to which the young Palestinian replies that he is a bus driver.
>
> Someone then screams: “Where are the soldiers?” as they express apparent surprise at the lack of Israeli military response and possibly seek to find out information.
>
> As more terrorists gather around Razeem, others can be heard calling for him to be let go. “He is a worker, he is from Jerusalem, leave him alone,” one person says.
>
> Nonetheless, Razeem was not spared in the massacre.
>
> His body was only identified on October 19, after his family spent 12 days frantically searching for news about him.

Finally, to prevent the argument that those are rogue elements or that civilians were not the intended targets. And what I think is the most important piece of evidence, we know that this attack was targeted from the very start at civilians, and that the terrorists had prepared information and documents on civilian targets. As shown in [this news article](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/hylk6npzt) the operation plan for attacking Kibbutz Miflasin, a civilian target said explicitly to take civilian hostages and harm civilians.

> In the document, the terrorists received clear orders to kidnap Israelis. "Take soldiers and civilians prisoner and hostage so that we would use them to negotiate," the document said. This is in contradiction to claims made by Salah al Arouri, a senior Hamas official, to Al Jazeera, that Hamas only targeted the military and that the Israelis were taken by civilians crossing the breached border fence.
> British Sky News reported overnight that a document found on a dead terrorist, which appears to be the same one described by the Times, referred to Kibbutz Miflasim, where the terrorists were repelled by local residents and prevented from invading.
>
> British Sky News reported overnight that a document found on a dead terrorist, which appears to be the same one described by the Times, referred to Kibbutz Miflasim, where the terrorists were repelled by local residents and prevented from invading.
>
> One page in the document titled, The Mission at Kibbutz Miflasim, said the Hamas force would be made up of two commanders and two teams of five. Sky also reported that the document included an order to abduct soldiers and civilians. One of the teams was told to breach the security fence and indicated the time it would take and that reinforcements would arrive within 3 to 5 minutes.

Comment: This answer makes a great job proving and documenting that the terrorists attacking Israel on Oct 7th were deliberately targeting civilians. But AFAIU the OP was already well aware of this, their question was rather smg like "is there any occurence documented on video where during these attacks (some of) the terrorists avoided targetting civilians ?" Of course, even if that existed (and proving a negative is difficult), that should not be used for neither denying nor minimizing the committed crimes (as the Queen's College student group is reported to do).

Comment: @Evargalo, around 3000 terrorists invaded into Gaza that day, but "only" ~1500 Israelis were killed. So mathematically there were some who didn't get to kill a civilian. Some of them attacked army bases and were repelled or killed  on the very beginning, they also didn't get to kill a civilian. Suhaib Razeem was assaulted by many terrorist, some of them even claimed that he should be released. Eventually he was found dead, probably one one of all the terrorists there actually killed him. Does it matter which one pressed the actual trigger?

Comment: @Evargalo I don't think the quote in the question is saying "There was at least one Hamas member who avoided killing civilians" - I think its trying to say that the general consensus amongst Hamas militants was to avoid civilian deaths. Otherwise the purpose of the post falls flat.

Comment: @SIMEL : The fact that some of the fighters/terrorists didn't kill any civilian is not the same as saying that they would have refrained to do so. I will let the OP precise whether my interpretation of their query was correct or if your answer fully responds to their question.

Comment: @Evargalo, I can't see another interpretation of the claim. If there exists one (or several) terrorists who said "no, I won't kill any women or children myself, I'll only help others who do" does it matter? They took part in an attack directly amed at harming civilians, even if they only fought against soldiers, it just means that they freed another terrorist to kill children at that time.

Comment: @SIMEL A court might care who pressed the actual trigger, or might declare anyone who took part in the attack to be complicit in every atrocity that took place. Sadly, I don't think Israel is going to provide the suspects with their day in court any more than the US allowed Bin Laden his day in court (many of the Palestinians currently in Israeli prisons have not been formally accused of anything either).

Comment: "There is clear evidence that the terrorists attacking Israel on Oct 7th were deliberately targeting civilians and civilian population centers." <- evidence that _many_ of the attackers deliberately targeted civilians etc. And that's why this is a partial answer to the question, because the attackers' behaviors were inconsistent. Some attacked civilians brutally and intentionally, some (it seems) incidentally and recklessly, some met civilians and intentionally failed to attack them, and some focused on military targets.

Comment: @einpoklum, this why the last paragraph exists. The commands were to attack a civilian Kibbutz and to take captive civilians. This shows that the goal of the attack was to attack civilians. Were there terrorists that decided to not kill a child or a woman at a certain point? perhaps, they still took part in the attack and directly or indirectly help those that had no problem of pulling the trigger on a handcuffed woman or a child. Also, there were some cases where civilians were taken hostages with the aim of taking them to Gaza but were liberated or managed to escape on the way.

Comment: SIMEL: Your last paragraph is actually somewhat misleading: Only a few of attackers are know to have had orders involving Israeli civilians; and perhaps more importantly - those orders do not correspond to the attacks we experienced on civilians, i.e. widespread killing (not during an attempt to abduct). That only buttresses my point regarding a spectrum of behaviors: A variety of orders/plans (including lack thereof) and different personal or group responses and behaviors when coming face to face with civilians.

Answer (score 5):

On October 13, 2023, Aljazeera reported on [videos released by Hamas](https://www.aljazeera.net/news/2023/10/13/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%88-%D9%8A%D8%B8%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%B9) that shows Hamas fighters taking care of and playing with Israeli children during the attacks:

> Publication of the military media affiliated with the Izz al-Din al-Qassam Brigades, the military wing of the Islamic Resistance Movement (Hamas); A video clip shows the way Al-Qassam fighters treat children, which invalidates the lies spread by Israel and its allies that the Palestinian resistance killed Israeli children. [via Google Translate]

In [this video](https://t.me/southfirstresponders/115) (requires Telegram, and may contain distressing images), published by the South First Responders group, there is a section showing a member of Hamas next to the back door of the car, shooting Israeli soldiers at a distance of 200 meters, while  two girls taking shelter behind the same car. It is clear that Hamas fighters did not shoot the two girls, when they could have easily done so.

**Update (Additional evidence):**

In [this video](https://t.me/southfirstresponders/5) (requires Telegram, and contain distressing images), published by the *South First Responders group* (the admin of this channel appears to be a member of IDF), shows Hamas members found a girl in a car (The video doesn't show what happened before that and I don't know why they didn't release all parts, obviously they have access to all the dash-cam videos) and kept her alive (presumably) as a hostage but at the end of the video, after Israeli soldiers arrived (about 200-300 meters away from the subject), the girl easily escaped from Hamas fighters. (Or the Hamas members let him to go and didn't even kill him) and she tried to inform Israeli soldiers that "I am here, help me .." but Israeli soldiers started shooting that girl at the end of the video and the girl took shelter behind a car.

**P.S.** If you think that this post is misleading please [see this meta post.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5005/61574)

Comment: [I have been unable to view the Telegram video - if someone could add in a description of what it shows, that would be helpful.]

Comment: After the edits, +1: This shows that the Muslim student group had *some* video evidence, however weak, to make their claims - which is what the original question was about. One can acknowledge this WITHOUT needing to accept whether this behaviour was universal, typical or even any more than staged propaganda.

Comment: This does answer the question where the claim came from. Thanks.

Comment: It's funny that the description calls the killings lies. The video does in no way invalidate the other ones and it is ridiculous to claim it does

Comment: @Oddthinking: I tried to respond to your comment on Telegram video by adding the related frame, but in the meta of this forum you recommended to not upload pictures (The frame shows a member of Hamas next to the back door of the car, shooting Israeli soldiers at a distance of 200 meters, and two girls taking shelter behind the same car!)

Comment: @C.F.G: Thanks for not posting it. I edited in that description, which was helpful.

Comment: Context is very needed, Hamas terrorist are playing with children in whos father they just murdered in front of their eyes. The second video is again lacking context. Those women were taken by Hamas and were able to run away once Israeli soldiers and police officers engaged them with fire. They didn't kill the girls because they tried to kidnap them, and then they don't kill them because they are fired upon. And again, both videos are from civilian towns, not sure where the first one is, the second is from Moshav Yachini, civilian targets with no military value.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the second video is supposed to demonstrate. It means that there was at least one Hamas fighter who was not some kind of over-the-top villain who would prioritize attacking children while soldiers were literally trying to kill them.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is clearly misleading in focusing on the answer to OP's literal question while omitting the fact that the literal question is of no consequence. A more intellectually honest answer would say: "Yes, there is some video evidence that some Hamas fighters taking part in the October 7 attack did not kill some civilians when they had the ability to kill them. However, since we know that Hamas is holding 240 hostages in Gaza, the fact that they did not kill literally everyone they could during the attacks is a priori obvious and useless as a defense of their actions."

Comment: Basically, imagine someone coming to the defense of a mass murderer by saying "But look! There's this one person the murderer could have killed, but didn't! We cannot allow the false narrative presented by the prosecution to become the accepted history of what happened." And then C.F.G. would write a Skeptics.se answer to confirm: yes, there is video evidence of the accused not killing this one person even though he could (while failing to mention that the murderer kidnapped that person in order to use him as a human shield and make it difficult for the authorities to capture him).

Comment: @DanRomik: The OP really asks "is there any video"? I answered yes there are many. What is wrong? [Also see this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56292/61574)

Comment: @C.F.G see the answer I posted to your meta question.

Comment: The general pattern here is: Person A says "X is true, therefore Y". Person B posts a question on Skeptics asking "A says that X is true, therefore Y. Is X true?" Person C posts an answer: "Yes, X is true", but fails to mention that X does not imply Y. The thing that's wrong is that this literal answer is technically correct but highly misleading because it leaves people with the impression that since you confirmed that X is true but did not discuss the problem with the claim that X implies Y, Y is true as well.

Comment: @DanRomik: But the question itself said "Y is trivially disprovable." and focussed itself on X.

Comment: Maybe it would be enough to add one line into the answer : "In conclusion, X is true. But X doesn't prove Y, which is trivially wrong, as acknowledged by OP and documented in the other answer" ?

Comment: @SIMEL: FWTW, some of those videos were discussed in Western media https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-hamas-propaganda-war in somewhat less kind/favorable terms [for Hamas] though.

Comment: @Oddthinking no, my "Y" does not refer to the claim "ZERO evidence that Palestinians deliberately killed women and children". "Y" in this case refers to the claim that because some Hamas attackers did not kill all the people they were attacking, that makes them more moral/ethical/righteous than some other hypothetical attacker group that does kill everyone. (To be fair, this claim is not stated explicitly in the post but is implicit from the context, since it's clear that's something the the student group quoted in OP believes.)

Comment: @Fizz if that context exists in the west, outside of the Hebrew speaking world, this just raises the question even more, why is this context missing from this answer?